# How to keep two or more mediacodec instance in Android

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, android-mediacodec, surface

I hava a VERTICAL viewPager2, viewHolder in it use SurfaceView to play mp4;

And at Any time, it only has one viewHolder instance, one surface to play video.

I hava two interface:

IMediaCodecProxy

```
interface IMediaCodecProxy {
    //all method like MediaCodec
    fun selectCodec()
    fun configureCodec()
    fun release()
    fun flush()
}
```

IMediaCodecPool

```
interface IMediaCodecPool {
    fun getCurrentCodec(): MediaCodecWrapper?
    fun selectorCodec(configure: MediaCodecAdapter.Configuration)
    fun resetAndStoreCodec(codec: MediaCodecWrapper)
}
```

IMediaCodecProxy is a proxy of MediaCodec, its methods signature equals MediaCodec;

What IMediaCodecPool is a pool to keep all configured/started mediaCodec instances;

I want to keep mediaCodec configured state when it released;

What I do is:

step1. when video play completed, IMediaCodecProxy#release while work

step2. if current codec instance can keep(some thing I limited it)

step3. IMediaCodecPool#resetAndStoreCodec work

step4. surface destroy, and next viewHolder create -> nextViewHolder's surface created, IMediaCodecProxy#newCodec(I create a new instance of codec because two video's mimeType different), than IMediaCodecProxy#configure where failed

I don't know what I need do in IMediaCodecPool#resetAndStoreCodec.

I try use codec#flush, but it is not useful

So, I don't know what went wrong, maybe in surface? maybe in MediaCodec? maybe in codec's state.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: some error info is :

`D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xc02e6808, reason connectToSurface

  E/SurfaceUtils: Failed to connect to surface 0xc02e6808, err -22

  E/MediaCodec: nativeWindowConnect returned an error: Invalid argument (-22)

  E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xffffffea, resetting...`

Comment: Instead of mediaCodec.release() -> create new codec instance try to use mediaCodec.stop() -> mediaCodec.configure() -> mediaCodec.start() using the same mediaCodec instance.